# Make UILabel focusable and tappable (tvOS)

Tags: focus, uilabel, tvos

I'm trying to implement 6 lines high description label and I want it to be focusable. Ideally that would mean extending UILabel class to make a custom component. I tried that by implementing `canBecomeFocused` and `didUpdateFocusInContext` but my UILabel doesn't seem to get any focus.

I also tried replacing UILabel with UIButton, but buttons aren't really optimised for this sort of thing. Also that would mean I'd need to change `buttonType` on focus from custom to plain.. and buttonType seems to be a ready-only property.

In reality I'd like to have exact same text label implemented by Apple in Apple TV Movies app. For movie description they have a text label that displays a few lines of text and a "more". When focused it looks like a button (shadows around) and changed background color. When tapped - it opens up a modal window with entire movie description.

[image]

Any suggestions? Or maybe someone has already implemented this custom control for tvOS? Or event better - there is a component from Apple that does this and I'm missing something.

P.S: Swift solution would be welcome :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, answering my own question :)

So it appears that some some views are "focusable" on tvOS out-of-the-box, and other have to be instructed to do so.

I finally ended up using `UITextView`, which has a `selectable` property, but if not one of these focusable views by default. Editing of `TextView` has to be disabled to make it look like `UILabel`. Also, currently there is a bug which prevents you from using `selectable` property from Interface Builder but works from code.

Naturally, `canBecomeFocused()` and `didUpdateFocusInContext` had to be implemented too. You'll also need to pass a `UIViewController` because `UITextView` is not capable of presenting a modal view controller. Bellow is what I ended up creating.

```
class FocusableText: UITextView {

    var data: String?
    var parentView: UIViewController?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "tapped:")
        tap.allowedPressTypes = [NSNumber(integer: UIPressType.Select.rawValue)]
        self.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

    func tapped(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        if let descriptionView = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("descriptionView") as? DescriptionViewController {
            if let view = parentView {
                if let show = show {
                    descriptionView.descriptionText = self.data
                    view.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.OverFullScreen
                    view.presentViewController(descriptionView, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override func canBecomeFocused() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func didUpdateFocusInContext(context: UIFocusUpdateContext, withAnimationCoordinator coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {

        if context.nextFocusedView == self {
            coordinator.addCoordinatedAnimations({ () -> Void in
                self.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.2).CGColor
            }, completion: nil)
        } else if context.previouslyFocusedView == self {
            coordinator.addCoordinatedAnimations({ () -> Void in
                self.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
            }, completion: nil)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I modified it a bit for my project. https://gist.github.com/Cedrick84/8922a0af730c39c05794

Comment: Has anything changed with tvOS lately that would cause this not to work? I still can't get a TextView to gain focus no matter what I try. I've gone down both routes by kernelpanic and @Cedrick .

Comment: Yeah, I made something similar for UIImageView and I was able to get it focused (even though its not inside a table or collectionview) but I couldn't get the TextView to work. No idea why right now as I've done everything mentioned above

Answer (score 5):

As for making a UILabel focusable:

```
class MyLabel: UILabel {

    override var canBecomeFocused: Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func didUpdateFocus(in context: UIFocusUpdateContext, with coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {
        super.didUpdateFocus(in: context, with: coordinator)

        backgroundColor = context.nextFocusedView == self ? .blue:.red

    }
}
```

IMPORTANT!!!
As stated on the apple developer portal:

The value of this property is true if the view can become focused; false otherwise.

By default, the value of this property is false. This property informs the focus engine if a view is capable of being focused. Sometimes even if a view returns true, a view may not be focusable for the following reasons:

- The view is hidden.
- The view has alpha set to 0.
- The view has userInteractionEnabled set to false.
- The view is not currently in the view hierarchy.

Answer (score 2):

Use a collection view with just one cell and add transform to cell and change cell background color in didUpdateFocusInContext when focus moves to cell.

```
override func didUpdateFocusInContext(context: UIFocusUpdateContext, withAnimationCoordinator coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {
    coordinator.addCoordinatedAnimations({
        if self.focused {
            self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.01, 1.01)
            self.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            self.textLabel.textColor = .blackColor()
        }
        else {
            self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1)
            self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
            self.textLabel.textColor = .whiteColor()
        }
        }, completion: nil)
}
```

As an additional step you could try to extract the color of the image if you are using the image as background like iTunes and use that for Visual effect view behind the cell.

Also you can apply transform to the collectionView in the video controller to make it look like in focus

Answer (score -4):

You can use system button, and set the background image in storyboard to an image that contains the color you would like

Comment: He wants to use UILabel or UITextView. Using system button is a horrible solution.

Comment: Yes, it is bad practice.