# Unexpected motion effect oscillations in tvOS

Tags: swift, tvos, uimotioneffect

I am experiencing motion effect oscillations using the following code

```
import UIKit  

@UIApplicationMain  
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {  
    var window: UIWindow?  

    func application(application: UIApplication,  
                     didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: 
                                               [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {  
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)  
        self.window!.rootViewController = ExampleController()  
        self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()  
        return true  
    }  
}  
class ExampleController: UIViewController {  
    override func viewDidLoad() {  
        super.viewDidLoad()  

        let redView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 200, y: 200, 
                                           width: 800, height: 500))  
        redView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.5)  
        self.view.addSubview(redView)  

        let effect = UIInterpolatingMotionEffect(keyPath: "center.x", 
                                                 type: .TiltAlongHorizontalAxis)  
        effect.minimumRelativeValue = -100  
        effect.maximumRelativeValue = 100  

        let effectGroup = UIMotionEffectGroup()  
        effectGroup.motionEffects = [effect]  

        redView.motionEffects = [effectGroup]  
    }
}
```

resulting in the following behavior both in Simulator and on the new Apple TV

[image]

Is there a way to avoid the oscillations?

Comment: Have you tried on a real device?

Comment: I have tested the code and I can completely reproduce it, however it seems the oscillation is already present in the tilt data so I would assume it is created when the touch is converted into simulated tilt. You should try it on real device.

Comment: Yes, same effect on the simulator and on the new Apple TV.

Answer (score 4):

I have tried your code in the simulator, printing the horizontal offset:

```
public class MyMotionEffect : UIInterpolatingMotionEffect {
    public override func keyPathsAndRelativeValuesForViewerOffset(viewerOffset: UIOffset) -> [String : AnyObject]? {
        print("\(viewerOffset.horizontal)")
    
        return super.keyPathsAndRelativeValuesForViewerOffset(viewerOffset);
    }
}
```

After a while I could reproduce the oscillation. The resulting (horizontal) offset has the following chart:

[image]

You can see the oscillation is already present in the tilt. It seems the device is generating two tilts at once.

One solution is to add heuristics (compare offset value with two previous and ignore if there was a sign change, or ignore offsets with abrupt change. Neither solution is perfect unfortunately).
The best solution would probably be to use Core Motion directly and avoid the native transformations entirely. Or use it with smaller distances because then the oscillation won't be visible.

Comment: The problem is that the real device (the new Apple TV) has exactly the same issue.

Comment: I believe that the two animations (left-to-right and right-to-left) are running at the same time and update view position one after another. It's not accelerometer/gyroscope related.

Comment: @Andrei Then you could probably add some heuristics that will ignore changes that are too big. Or you can add heuristics that detect the change of sign. For example, you could always save the offset and don't propagate it until the next event comes. If the two offsets have different signs, you could ignore them and wait for the next event. Or you could use only the one of them. Both approaches have their problems. I feel this is a bug in the device because this really shouldn't happen.

Comment: Also, one of the problem is that `UIMotionEffect` was probably never expected to move the views hundreds of pixels. It was probably meant to create a 5 px effect... and the oscillation there would be easily lost.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code too. This is not a problem about the simulator.
The problem comes only when you change the touch direction too fast.
The `UIInterpolatingMotionEffect` starts a new motion **before** finishing to interpolate the previous one.
So there happen to be two motions acting on your view concurrently.