# Showing long texts on tvOS

Tags: uilabel, uitextview, tvos

In the Movies application, when the description of a movie is too long, it is truncated and a MORE button appears at the end of the text. The text is also focusable so I can tap on it and it displays the full text in full screen.

I can't figure out how to reproduce the same thing in my app. Is it non-documented behaviour of `UITextView` or `UILabel`? Is it a component developed by Apple but not published yet? How can I do that in my own apps?

Comment: They probably use `UITextView`. See these answers: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33889964/2128900, http://stackoverflow.com/q/34158882/2128900

Answer (score 0):

The Movies iTunes app on tvOS is written using TVML and Javascript and is not a traditional native Swift app. Text overflow is handled by TVML:

```
 <description allowsZooming="true"
      moreLabel="more"
      action="showOverflow"
      title="{{title}}">{{description}}
    </description>
```

Comment: It's crazy that some features like that in TVML are not replicated in native APIs. TVML seems so limited in other ways that I didn't even consider it as an option for my app.